# Create a bash command that takes json file as a argument

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I have a bash command sendTransact that send a transaction to the server. But the transaction itself is available in a different json file. So i need to be able to do something like:

```
$ sendTransact <fileName.json>
```

which appends the contents of `<fileName.json>` to sendTransact.

sendTransact:

```
sendTransaction(){
    echo $1 | \
        http --verbose  POST "http://localhost:8081/v1.1/payments?provide_explanations=true" \
        | cat $0
}
```

sendTransaction

Comment: from which input channel (stdin, file, ...) can the http command read data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to pipe it.  So either...

```
cat file.json | sendTransact
```

Or...

```
sendTransact < file.json
```

(they do the same thing)

You'll have to make sure your sendTransact supports parsing stdin for input which not all programs do.  But well constructed programs do.  If instead that command uses a parameter and itself reads input, you may need something like...

```
sendTransact -f file.json
```